# Disable global keyboard shortcut in Sculpt mode only

Tags: sculpt-mode

I currently have the 'Move' function(transform.translate) mapped to button 'D' in general (**3D View > 3D View(Global) > Move**)

However, in Sculpt mode Only, I wish to disable the keymapping for 'D' key. I tried adding a  'none' command to button 'D' in (**3D View > Sculpt > Sculpt (Global**))

[image]

BUT the 'D' key mapping in 3D View(Global) seems to have higher priority and overrides it. I also tried to reassign another shortcut to 'Move' here but still the 3d View(Global) has higher precedence.

How can i disable the 'D' buttom mapping only in Sculpt mode?